# Access webservice on pageload

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, web-services

I'm developing a website in VB.Net, visual studio 2010, that requires accessing a webservice to access the user's login information.

They are logged in through a separate page and when they redirect to my page I access their credentials through the webservice and then handle the session through my own scripts.

What I need to know is:

Can a webservice be checked on pageload if a condition isn't met?

I have not worked with webservices before and have no clue how to add parameters or how to get a value from it. Is it possible to add the reference to my login class(or a class in general)?

I have added a reference through the visual studio: website -> add web reference

But this simply generated a bunch of files and I can't find a good tutorial online about how to use the generated references/files.

I thought it was supposed to generate some class files, however it added a folder (.discomap) with the following types:

- .disco
- .wsdl
- .xsd

Finally, can I test this webservice (which is online and running) on my local host?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're wanting to call these services from your code behind.

When you added a web reference it should have generated a bunch of class files you can use to call the service methods. You should be able to do this from localhost.

A WCF service call from the code behind would look something like this

```
ServiceReference1.Service1Client client = new
    ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
string returnString;

returnString = client.GetData(Param);
label1.Text = returnString;
```

Comment: This is a good start! I don't think it actually created any class files though. It generated a .discomap file with a .disco, .wsdl, .xsd, .wsdl, and two more .xsd files. I will edit my post to include that.

Comment: I haven't added a reference in VS2010 for a while but I think maybe the service wasn't consumed properly if you didn't get any classes. Did you check out this guide: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628649%28v=vs.100%29.aspx? You should be able to substitute what you use for step 7 to do something like the dummy code I wrote out

Comment: I have seen that page, yes, but I think my problem is that I'm using 2010 and the webservice was made using vs 2008. Somehow I need to add the reference using the Network 2.0 framework.

Comment: Is it a public service? I can try to add reference from my machine

Comment: Afraid not. It's private that requires username/password credentials. Not sure if that also is part of the problem.

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem, you just have to set up credentials object before calling the service. Maybe the service provider has some integration examples you can copy/paste from?